# How does VB.Net evaluate the end test of a FOR...NEXT loop?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I am teaching students about the FOR NEXT loop in VB.Net and I seem to be burdened with an understanding from learning Assembly language long ago. Trying to count the number of iterations that a line of code would do in several cases:

```
FOR x = 1 TO 1  (implied STEP 1)  
  (body)  
NEXT x
```

Should do 1 loop, right? But I read the test as "until x is 1", so after the first loop, x becomes 2 and the test should not work.
How about: `FOR x = 1 TO 1 STEP -1`? Is your answer the same?
How about: `FOR x = 1 TO 0 (implied STEP 1)`? The body should never execute. But the test is "until x = 0", so it should cause an infinite loop as x climbs away from 0... Starting to see the issue?
How about: `FOR x = 1 TO 0 STEP -1`? Now it will do the body twice, right? But what is x at that point? -1. How did the test stop when it is one beyond what is says it will stop at?
I guess the compiler is actually testing `until x = (endval) + stepval`. I can visualize that in Assembler, but otherwise I confess that I can't see or explain to my students how this all actually works the way it is assumed it "should". (This question seems trivial with constants like "1", but imagine variables or other ways of creating the FOR loop parameters.) Can anyone shed some light? Thank you.

Comment: See "Technical Implementation" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx midway down the page.

Comment: In addition to Tony's comment (who can type faster than me :p ), note that you should not rely on the exit value of the counter variable to be anything in particular. If you need to use the value, assign it to another variable at the appropriate point.

Comment: I see in the reference that Tony Hinkle provided, that the test is actually checking for any value "beyond" the endval (in the appropriate direction for the stepval). Fine, but the condition appears to be an Equal To test, and so it seems perplexing to read, and especially to describe. I guess that's programming for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Tony Hinkle provided the answer, but did so as a comment.  So I'm providing the particular text he mentioned here, as an answer:

"When a For...Next loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates start, end, and step. Visual Basic evaluates these values only at this time and then assigns start to counter. Before the statement block runs, Visual Basic compares counter to end. If counter is already larger than the end value (or smaller if step is negative), the For loop ends and control passes to the statement that follows the Next statement. Otherwise, the statement block runs.

Each time Visual Basic encounters the Next statement, it increments counter by step and returns to the For statement. Again it compares counter to end, and again it either runs the block or exits the loop, depending on the result. This process continues until counter passes end or an Exit For statement is encountered.

The loop doesn't stop until counter has passed end. If counter is equal to end, the loop continues. The comparison that determines whether to run the block is counter <= end if step is positive and counter >= end if step is negative."

To help clarify:

FOR x = 1 TO 1  (implied STEP 1) will loop 1 time.

FOR x = 1 TO 1 STEP -1 will loop 1 time.

FOR x = 1 TO 0 (implied STEP 1) will never loop because counter is already past end.

FOR x = 1 TO 0 STEP -1 will loop twice

Comment: Thank you for summarizing the answer in to an Answer here. I understand how it works now and can explain it properly. My error was in seeing it as an "until = end" type of loop, which makes no sense. I hope that this clear explanation is useful to someone else.